# How to specify the correct return type of SQLiteDatabase.query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

Android Studio has me running in circles! With the following code

```
fun fetchAllPOIs(): Cursor? {
    if (myDbHelper.myDataBase != null)
        return myDbHelper.myDataBase!!.query(
        "POIs", arrayOf(
            "Name", "Type",
            "Latitude", "Longitude", "_id"
        ), null, null, null, null, null
    )
}
```

Android Studio marks an error at the closing } , saying

> A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body.

The suggested Quick Fix is

> Remove explicitly specified return type of enclosing function 'DBAdapter.fetchAllPOIs'

If I accept the quick fix the code looks like

```
    fun fetchAllPOIs() {
    if (myDbHelper.myDataBase != null)
        return myDbHelper.myDataBase!!.query(
        "POIs", arrayOf(
            "Name", "Type",
            "Latitude", "Longitude", "_id"
        ), null, null, null, null, null
    )
}
```

with most of the function underlined. The suggested Quick Fix is

> Change return type of enclosing function to 'Cursor?'

When I accept this I get back to square one!

How do I get out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go back to your original source:

```
fun fetchAllPOIs(): Cursor? {
    if (myDbHelper.myDataBase != null)
        return myDbHelper.myDataBase!!.query(
        "POIs", arrayOf(
            "Name", "Type",
            "Latitude", "Longitude", "_id"
        ), null, null, null, null, null
    )
}
```

What is supposed to be returned if `myDbHelper.myDataBase == null`? The compiler does not know, because you have not told it what to return.

Let's pretend that you want to return `null`.

You have three possible solutions. The Java-style solution is:

```
fun fetchAllPOIs(): Cursor? {
    if (myDbHelper.myDataBase != null) {
        return myDbHelper.myDataBase!!.query(
        "POIs", arrayOf(
            "Name", "Type",
            "Latitude", "Longitude", "_id"
        ), null, null, null, null, null)
    } else {
      return null
    }
}
```

You have the more Kotlin-y "lift the return out of the if/else" approach:

```
fun fetchAllPOIs(): Cursor? {
    return if (myDbHelper.myDataBase != null) {
      myDbHelper.myDataBase!!.query(
        "POIs", arrayOf(
            "Name", "Type",
            "Latitude", "Longitude", "_id"
        ), null, null, null, null, null)
    } else {
      null
    }
}
```

And you have the very Kotlin-y safe call approach:

```
fun fetchAllPOIs(): Cursor? {
    return myDbHelper.myDataBase?.query(
        "POIs", arrayOf(
            "Name", "Type",
            "Latitude", "Longitude", "_id"
        ), null, null, null, null, null)
}
```

`?.` is the "safe call" operator. If `myDbHelper.myDataBase` is not `null`, it calls `query()`. If `myDbHelper.myDataBase` *is* `null`, `?.` skips the `query()` call and evaluates to `null`.

If you were planning on returning something else other than `null`, then some of this will need revising.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to write such a helpful reply.